# c3js change title of tooltip for timeseries chart

Tags: tooltip, c3.js

In c3.js I want to change the title of the tooltip in the timeseries chart, By default, the title of the tooltip is the time of the X-series.

I have a unique text label for each time point which I store as a data series in rows: [ ], but I can't retrieve this unique text label to show in the tooltip.

My data is:

```
rows: [
        ['Date', 'Type', 'Pages', 'Words'],
        ['2013-01-01', 'A', 120, 300],
        ['2013-01-02', 'B', 160, 240],
        ['2013-01-03', 'C', 200, 290],
        ['2013-01-04', 'D', 160, 230],
        ['2013-01-05', 'E', 130, 300],
        ['2013-01-06', 'F', 220, 320]
],
```

Currently the title of the tooltip is showing the X-series date, which is basically:

```
title = d[0].x;
```

I modified tooltip: {} like this

```
title = d[0].value;
```

but the title of the tooltip shows *null*, instead of showing the text corresponding to the 2nd column.

Then when I do this:

```
title = d[1].value;
```

the screen can show the number corresponding to the 3rd column.

Is there a problem showing a text field as the title of the tooltip? I wouldn't think so if it can show the date by default.

Please let me know how to show the 2nd column data as the title of the tooltip. The 2nd column data basically describes the event occurring at that date.

Full code for tooltip: {} is below:

```
tooltip: {
    contents: function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
      var $$ = this, config = $$.config,
          titleFormat = config.tooltip_format_title || defaultTitleFormat,
          nameFormat = config.tooltip_format_name || function (name) { return name; },
          valueFormat = config.tooltip_format_value || defaultValueFormat, text, i, title, value, name, bgcolor;

          title = d[0].x ; //title of tooltip is X-axis label
          //title = d[0].name; //shows Type as the tooltip title
          //title = d[0].value; //shows null as the tooltip title
          //title = d[1].value; //shows Page number as the tooltip title

      for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
          if (! (d[i] && (d[i].value || d[i].value === 0))) { continue; }


          if (! text) {
              text = "<table class='" + $$.CLASS.tooltip + "'>" + (title || title === 0 ? "<tr><th colspan='2'>" + title + "</th></tr>" : ""); //for the tooltip title
          }

          name = nameFormat(d[i].name); //for the columns data
          value = valueFormat(d[i].value, d[i].ratio, d[i].id, d[i].index);
          bgcolor = $$.levelColor ? $$.levelColor(d[i].value) : color(d[i].id);

          text += "<tr class='" + $$.CLASS.tooltipName + "-" + d[i].id + "'>";
          text += "<td class='name'><span style='background-color:" + bgcolor + "'></span>" + name + "</td>";
          text += "<td class='value'>" + value + "</td>";
          text += "</tr>";
      }
      return text + "</table>";
  }        
}, //tooltip
```